# How to change from regexp_extract to regexp_substr in Snowflake

Tags: hive, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, hiveql

I have some expressions in Hive that I need to change into Snowflake

(regexp_extract(subtransactionxml,'(.*?)()',1) in('REFUND'))

I tried to use this one but it gives me 0 results

(regexp_substr(subtransactionxml,'\W+(\W+)',1,1,'e',1) in('REFUND'))

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Can you provide a sample input and the part you wanted to extract?

Comment: <transactionDate>2019-07-26T14:06:05.575-04:00</transactionDate>  <type>CANCEL</type> I need to exctract value that is between <type>*</type>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your sample, the following query should work:

```
with xmldata as (
select '<transactionDate>2019-07-26T14:06:05.575-04:00</transactionDate> <type>CANCEL</type>' subtransactionxml )
select regexp_substr(subtransactionxml,'<type>(.*)<\/type>',1,1,'e',1) in ('CANCEL')
from xmldata;
```